# Stopwatch frontend app stop, when tab is not active

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, web-deployment

I build a frontend app for managing time. Everything work but when I am switching to another tab (without closing the app tab) the stopwatch is stopped.
This is the website:  https://tasks-time-manager.netlify.app/
And this is more or less what the code does:

```
playBtn.addEventListener('click', playBtnClickedHandler);

function playBtnClickedHandler(this: HTMLButtonElement) {
   setTimeout(()=>{
       //Update the UI by 10 miliseconds
    },10)
   }
```

How can I make the app work when the tab is not currently displayed?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Comment: [Huge dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=stopwatch+tab+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)